# Replace "@" with the text "at" in changing the time

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time

I have a wordpress blog and I wanted to show to the users website last updated. In the code bellow I have `mysql2date('j F Y **@** H:i', $last);`.

I just want to replace the "@" with a text like this: "Last updated 3 March 2013 "***at***" 11:39"

Here is the original code:

```
<?php
$last = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_modified FROM $wpdb->posts order by post_modified DESC LIMIT 1");
echo "Last updated " . mysql2date('j F Y @ H:i', $last);
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? You know there is some documentation for that function? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/mysql2date

Answer (score 3):

You can't just write "at" in a format string, as I'm sure you know, because the function would interpret each letter as a time\date variable.  But you can include normal letters in a date format string, without them being interpreted as time/date variables, by "escaping" them using backslashes:

`'j F Y \a\t H:i'`

The documentation for time/date format strings in PHP (which Wordpress uses) is available here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(post_modified, "Last updated %e %M %Y at %k:%i") FROM ...
```